# cometd @RemoteCall. downgrading from cometd 3 to 2

Tags: java, cometd, downgrade

I need to downgrade my existing cometd application to use cometd 2 instead of 3 as new client is not willing to upgrade their environments.
As I know @RemoteCall annotation was introduced only in cometd 3. I do not have any experience with cometd 2 and I was unable to find anything googling. Anyone has idea or knows how to correctly replace this to work on cometd 2?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is no plan to backport the `@RemoteCall` functionality to CometD 2.

Having said that, you have two choices.

The first is to use the [CometD commercial support](http://docs.cometd.org/3/reference/#_support).

The second is to reimplement the `@RemoteCall` functionality using service channels for your needs. This won't be difficult and it's how it is implemented in CometD 3; service channels are available in CometD 2 as well.

Comment: sbordet, thanks for replying. Maybe you could provide an example of using service channels that could replace the @RemoteCall methods?